# how to fix passing variable from view to html

Tags: python, django

i have a problem passing variable 'res' from view to index.html, it's return the last result in the html page

view file:

```py
def index(request):

    posts = Layout.objects.all()
    urlpost = SiteUrls.objects.all()[:20]


    field_value = SiteUrls.objects.values_list('site_url', flat=True)

    for site_url in field_value:
        print(site_url)
        res = os.system("ping -n 1 " + site_url )

        if res == 0:
            res = "connected"
        else:
            res = "not connected"

    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'urlpost':urlpost,
        'res': res
    }

    return render (request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

html file:

```html
      <table>
        <tbody>
            {% for SiteUrls in urlpost %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{SiteUrls.site_title}}</td>
            <td>{{SiteUrls.site_url}}</td>

            <td> {{res}} </td>

            <td><a style="margin-bottom:10px" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">open Site</a></td>
          </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

i would like to get back the specific result for each line

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with passing values. This is a simple logic issue: you have a single `res` variable, and you overwrite it each time. Presumably you want a `res` value for *each* site_url.

Comment: Besides @DanielRoseman's comment, you are passing 2 querysets and a variable to your template. Showing them together will be hard. You need to create a data structure to combine your ping results with the model objects. And then iterate over that in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.values_list()`. Work with the objects instead and add your value as an additional attribute.

Note that in your code, you are limiting your `SiteUrls` query to 20 objects, but then you ping all `SiteUrls` in your DB. I assume you only want to ping these 20 `SiteUrls`.

```
def index(request):

    posts = Layout.objects.all()
    urlpost = list(SiteUrls.objects.all()[:20])

    for site_url in urlpost:
        print(site_url.site_url)
        res = os.system("ping -n 1 " + site_url.site_url )

        if res == 0:
            site_url.res = "connected"
        else:
            site_url.res = "not connected"

    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'urlpost':urlpost,
    }

    return render (request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

Template:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        {% for SiteUrls in urlpost %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{SiteUrls.site_title}}</td>
        <td>{{SiteUrls.site_url}}</td>

        <td> {{SiteUrls.res}} </td>

        <td><a style="margin-bottom:10px" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">open Site</a></td>
      </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also, it is generally considered a bad idea to call system processes like that in a web request like you are doing here. Once you got this to work, I encourage you to research the concept of task queues.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects in `urlpost` and `res` are in the same order, you can use python's [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and merge them together as tuples, then iterate through this tuple list in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass it as a temporary attribute:

```
def index(request):

    posts = Layout.objects.all()
    urlpost = SiteUrls.objects.all()[:20]
    field_value = SiteUrls.objects.values_list('site_url', flat=True)

    for site_url in field_value:
        print(site_url)
        res = os.system("ping -n 1 " + site_url )

        if res == 0:
            site_url.res = "connected"
        else:
            site_url.res = "not connected"

        context = {
            'posts':posts,
            'urlpost':urlpost,
            }

    return render (request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

and you can access in your loop in the template like:

```
{{SiteUrls.res}}
```